# Connect userId with a unique photo in Firebase

Tags: java, firebase

I have an app where it is possible to create an user and this work perfectly and I am happy!

In a simple way, here is a method that adds the user to the Firebase database:

```
    public void addUserInfoToDatabase(){
    String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    final DatabaseReference the_user_database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserRegistraion").child(user_id);


    Map userAttributes = new HashMap();
    userAttributes.put("user_id", user_id);
    userAttributes.put("username", userName);
    userAttributes.put("name", name);
    userAttributes.put("e-mail", email);

    the_user_database.setValue(userAttributes);
    if (mRegistrationListener != null)
        mRegistrationListener.onRegistrationComplete(true); // Assumes success

}
```

And here is how the table looks when the user is registered:

[image: User table]

What I want to do now is that I want the possibility to add a profile picture which belongs to each user: e,g a profile picture, family-picture etc.

The question is: how can i do this in Firebase? I am not asking anyone to do this for me, but just to give me a good tip or provide a guide/video for how to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create a separate activity for setting up a profile photo. Maybe instead of calling onRegistrationComplete call an onCompleteListener after setValue(userAttributes) like this:

```
the_user_database.setValue(userAttributes).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener...){
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddProfileActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the next activity it could be a simple XML layout with a button and an ImageView.

This code can open your gallery, select an image, and place it in your imageview in the onActivityResult method:

```
private void selectPhotoFromGallery(){
        Log.d(TAG, "selectPhotoFromGallery: started");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_PICK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
                contentUri = data.getData();
                try{
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentUri);
                    profile_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }catch (IOException e){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You would then need a method to upload your image to FirebaseStorage and capture the downloadUrl to add to the desired node. In this case because you are adding to an existing node you call updateChildren() when adding the profile photo. I use a method like this:

```
private void uploadProfileImage(){
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadProfileImage: uploading image....");
        if (contentUri != null){
            //from gallery
            final StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(currentUserID).child("profile_photo");
            reference.putFile(contentUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            String profilePhotoUri = uri.toString();
                            DatabaseReference publicUserReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("public_user")
                                    .child(currentUserID);
                            HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
                            hashMap.put("profile_photo", profilePhotoUri);
                            publicUserReference.updateChildren(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CompleteProfileActivity.class);
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

You would need to adjust this for your specific needs obviously. The thing you are really trying to do is to save an image to Storage and get the http://... string location where it is stored and then insert that information into the same location as the previous information you provided.

I hope this counts as a helpful tip. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPOhnTnLcSY That's a link to a video about uploading images to Firebase storage for more information if you need it. Good luck!